# Secure ownership defaults for XAMPP on OS X?

Tags: php, security, xampp

I've run into many cases on XAMPP/OS X where I've simply resolved to `chmod -R 777 .` on each project directory. Are there any sensible configurations for an XAMPP installation to run safely on something like `755` or `775`?

For example, what would be a smart..

- User/group to run PHP as?
- `chmod` level?
- `chown` setup?